# How to customize the material UI textfield datetime picker?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui, datetimepicker

I am implementing a material UI date-time picker with the material-ui textfield component. It works alright but I can't find any documentation for customizing the content in the calendar/time-picker popup.

I don't want to use the material-ui/pickers library, as upgrading from my current version could present challenges.

I need to find a way to adjust calendar styling, the date scope (only months should be viewable - should not be able to toggle the year), and remove the visual time picker in the pop-up. Is there a way to do this in the vanilla textfield date-time picker?

```
<TextField
  id="datetime-local"
  label="End Time"
  type="datetime-local"
  defaultValue={moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm')}
  clearable={true}
  InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: true,
  }}
/>
```